# How to set default view in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an interactive application using matplotlib to draw some graphs. It also uses the matplotlib toolbar to allow some interactions with the graph. If I plot a new set of date in the same graph, with updated limits for the axes, it works fine. However, if I hit the Home button in the toolbar, it brings me to the coordinates from the first plot I did. Is there a way to update the default view of my graph using new coordinates, in such a way the Home button leads me to the right coordinates?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090069/how-to-reset-navigatontoolbar-history-when-re-plotting-data-on-the-same-axis/16090951#16090951