# How to create a new plot which is already zoomed once in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a new plot which is already zoomed once. means that if I hit the home button it will return full view.
This is similar to using the box zoom button but programmatically.
something like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot(range(10)) # just some plot
axes.set_zoomed_xlim(3,7) #different from set_xlim because you can see the whole plot if you hit Home
```

Do you guys know something like this magic set_zoomed_xlim ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090069/how-to-reset-navigatontoolbar-history-when-re-plotting-data-on-the-same-axis/16090951#16090951 which is doing something related (blowing away the history).  This is not something that mpl supports in a nice way (yet!).